# Why wont this code tp my player to to the given vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to teleport a player to the start of my level when it hits the finish line. I have made a vector3 with the position i want to tp my player to(x, y, z position) Here is the code:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Finish")
        {
            Player.transform.position = Start;
        }
```

Comment: You should make the question more clear. Add more details. What's `Start`? Is `OnCollisionEnter` called?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including all relevant details. Do you get any errors? If so include them as well. Have you tried [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) ? Are you sure the tag is correctly assigned to your object and there is no typo? In general use `CompareTag` instead of `==`, it prevents typos.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have your position kept in yout class in a class vectro3 variable.
Then set that position OnCollisionEnter.

```
Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(0,0,0);

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Finish")
    {
        Player.transform.position = startPos;
    }
}
```

You can set it in the variable declaration or get it in the `Start()`

```
Vector3 startPos;

void Start() {
    startPos = transform.position;
}
```

Not debuggued code.